# Codeigniter - Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, frameworks

This is the code which is causing this error,

```
if(!$seg1)
        {
            $recent = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,8);    
            /**line number 24**/ $this->DATA['recents'] = $recent->result();
             $action = "home";      
        }                   

        else    
        {
            if(in_array($seg1, $pages))
                $action = $seg1;
            else
                $action = 'review';
        }
```

What's the problem? It returns this error for "line number 24". 
I've tried this :

```
$recent = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,8);    

$q = $recent->query("SELECT * FROM sites");
```

but still no luck.
Here's the complete code, You can check the controllers here to find if they have any problems. But I don't think so :

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {


    public function index($seg1 = false,$seg2 = false , $seg3=false,$seg4=false)
    {       

        $pages= array(
                config_item("slug_login"),
                config_item("slug_logout"),
                config_item("slug_user"),
                config_item("slug_register"),
                config_item("slug_pages"),              
                config_item("slug_contact"),                
                config_item("slug_last"),               
                config_item("slug_filter"),             
                config_item("slug_top")             
            );
        if(!$seg1)
        {
            $recent = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,8);    
             $this->DATA['recents'] = $recent->result();
             $action = "home";      
        }                   

        else    
        {
            if(in_array($seg1, $pages))
                $action = $seg1;
            else
                $action = 'review';
        }

        switch ($action) {
            case  config_item("slug_logout"):                   
                $this->session->sess_destroy();                 
                redirect(base_url(),'location');                
                exit;
                break;                      
            case  config_item("slug_register"):                 
                if($this->input->get("v"))
                {
                    $this->validateAccount($this->input->get("v"));     
                }       

                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Register");
                $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]   = __("Create a FREE account.");

                break;          
            case  config_item("slug_login"):            
                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Login");
                $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]   = __("Login into your account.");           
                if($this->input->get("r") == '1')
                {
                    $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Recovery Password");
                    $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]   = __("Recovery Your Password"); 
                    $action = 'recovery';
                }                           
                break;                      

            case  config_item("slug_pages"):                    
                $page = $this->Admin->getTable("pages",array("slug" => $seg2));
                if($page->num_rows() == 0)
                {
                    show_404();
                }
                $this->DATA['page'] = $page->row();
                $recent                 = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,7);    
                 $this->DATA['recents']     = $recent->result();

                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = $this->DATA['page']->title;
                $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]   = more(strip_tags($this->DATA['page']->text),200);

                $action = 'page';
                break;          

            case  config_item("slug_last"):                 

                $data               = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,18);    
                $this->DATA['list']     = $data->result();
                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Latest Updated Sites");

                $top                = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"score desc",false,false,7);    
                $this->DATA['top']  = $top->result();



                $action = 'list';
                break;          


            case  config_item("slug_top"):                  

                $data               = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"score desc",false,false,18);    
                $this->DATA['list']     = $data->result();
                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Latest Updated Sites");

                $recents                = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,7);    
                $this->DATA['recents']  = $recents->result();



                $action = 'list';
                break;  

            case  config_item("slug_filter"):   


                $seg2 = mb_strtolower($seg2);

                $filter = array("tag","ip","city","country","region","isp",config_item('slug_made_with'));
                if(!in_array($seg2, $filter))
                {

                    show_404();
                    die();
                }
                if(intval($seg4)==0)
                    $seg4 = 1;
                if(intval($seg4)<=1)
                    $offset = 0;
                else
                    $offset = 12*intval($seg4);
                $limit  = 13;
                $this->DATA['offset'] = $offset;
                $this->DATA['currentPage'] = $seg4;
                $this->DATA['filter'] = $seg2;
                $this->DATA['search'] = $seg3;

                $seg2_text  = __(urldecode($seg2));
                $seg3       = urldecode($seg3);

                if($seg2 == config_item('slug_made_with'))
                {

                    $seg3 = _clean_special(urldecode($seg3));
                    $seg3 = urldecode($seg3);
                    $seg2_text = "Made With";
                    $data               = $this->db->query("SELECT {PRE}sites.*,{PRE}technologies.icon FROM {PRE}sites,{PRE}technologies WHERE {PRE}sites.url = {PRE}technologies.url AND {PRE}technologies.name = '$seg3' AND {PRE}sites.completed = 1 ORDER BY {PRE}sites.metaTitle ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");    
                    $this->DATA['list']     = $data->result();
                    $this->DATA['title']        = __("Filter sites by ").ucfirst(mb_strtolower($seg2_text)).": <img  style='vertical-align: text-top ;height:40px;' src='".base_url()."assets/images/icons/".$this->DATA['list'][0]->icon."'> ".$seg3." - ".__("Page ").$seg4;

                }
                else
                {

                    if($seg2 == 'ip' || $seg == 'tag')
                    {

                        if($seg == 'tag')
                        {
                            $seg3 = _clean_special(urldecode($seg3));
                            $field = 'metaKeywords';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $field = "ip";
                            $seg3 = _clean_ip(urldecode($seg3));
                        }

                        $data               = $this->db->query("SELECT {PRE}sites.* FROM {PRE}sites WHERE  {PRE}sites.$field  LIKE '%$seg3%'  AND {PRE}sites.completed = 1 ORDER BY {PRE}sites.metaTitle ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset");    
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        $data               = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1,$seg2 => urldecode($seg3)),"metaTitle asc",false,$offset,$limit);    
                    }
                    $this->DATA['list']     = $data->result();
                    $this->DATA['title']        = __("Filter sites by ").ucfirst(mb_strtolower($seg2_text)).": ".$seg3." - ".__("Page ").$seg4; 

                }

                $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = __("Filter sites by ").ucfirst(mb_strtolower($seg2_text)).": ".$seg3." - ".__("Page ").$seg4;     


                $recents                = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,7);    
                $this->DATA['recents']  = $recents->result();

                if(count($this->DATA['list'] ) == 0)
                {
                    show_404();
                    die();
                }

                $action = 'list';
                break;          


            case  config_item("slug_contact"):                  
                    if($this->input->post())
                    {
                        if(validateCaptcha($this->input->post("g-recaptcha-response")))
                        {     
                            $subject        = $this->input->post("subject");
                            $message        = $this->input->post("message");
                            $names          = $this->input->post("names");
                            $email          = $this->input->post("email");
                            $email_admin    = get_email_admin();
                            if($subject && $message && $names && $email)
                            {
                                $message2 = "<strong>Names:</strong><br>$names <br>";
                                $message2 .= "<strong>Email:</strong><br>$email <br>";
                                $message2 .= "<strong>Message:</strong><br>$message <br>";
                                $message2 .= "<br><br>---- Contact Form";
                                if(email($email_admin,$subject,$message2))
                                {
                                    $this->session->set_flashdata('contact_message', __("Message Sent"));
                                    redirect(base_url().config_item("slug_contact"),'location');
                                    exit; 
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('contact_error', __("Captcha Error"));
                            redirect(base_url().config_item("slug_contact"),'location');
                            exit;  
                        }
                    }

                break;          


            case  config_item("slug_user"): 
                if(!is_logged())  
                {            
                        redirect(base_url().config_item("slug_login"),'location');
                    exit;
                }

                $bookmarks = $this->db->query("SELECT {PRE}sites.* from {PRE}sites,{PRE}bookmarks WHERE {PRE}bookmarks.iduser= "._user("id")." AND {PRE}sites.id = {PRE}bookmarks.idsite ORDER BY score DESC");
                $this->DATA['page'] = $seg2;
                $this->DATA['bookmarks'] = $bookmarks->result();
                 if($this->input->post("names"))
                 {
                    $this->Admin->updateTable("users",array("names" => _clean_special($this->input->post("names"))),array("id" => _user("id")));
                 } 

                 if($this->input->post("password"))
                 {
                    $password   = $this->input->post("password",TRUE);
                    $password2  = $this->input->post("password-r",TRUE);
                    if($password == $password2)
                    {
                        if(strlen($password) >=5)
                        {
                            $this->Admin->updateTable("users",array("password" => sha1($this->input->post("password"))),array("id" => _user("id")));    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('update_error', __("The password length is very short, please add more than 5 characters"));                          
                            $error = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('update_error', __("Password doesn't match"));                            
                        $error = true;
                    }


                 }

                if($this->input->post())
                {
                    if(!$error)
                    {
                        $user       = $this->Admin->getTable("users",array("id" => _user("id")));                    
                        $data_user = $user->row_array();
                        $this->session->set_userdata("user",$data_user);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('update_message', __("Your account has been updated successfully"));
                    }
                    redirect(base_url().config_item("slug_user")."/".$seg2,'location');
                    exit;    
                }

                break;          


            case  "review":     
                $this->load->helper('seo');             
                 $site                  = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("url" => $seg1));
                 if($site->num_rows() == 0)
                    show_404();

                 $site_data = $site->row();
                 $score1                = $site_data->score-20;
                 $score2                = $site_data->score;
                 $recent                = $this->Admin->getTable("sites",array("completed" => 1),"updated desc",false,false,7);    
                 $technologies          = $this->Admin->getTable("technologies",array("url" => $seg1));    
                 $similar               = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM {PRE}sites WHERE score BETWEEN $score1 AND $score2 AND completed = 1 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 7");    


                 $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]        = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($site_data->url))." ".__("- SEO Checker - Website Review");
                 $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]  = ucfirst(mb_strtolower($site_data->url))." ".__(" - Website Review, SEO, Estimation Traffic and Earnings And Speed And Optimization Tips ");
                 $this->DATA['site']        = $site_data;
                 $this->DATA['recents']     = $recent->result();
                 $this->DATA['similar']     = $similar->result();
                 $this->DATA['technologies']    = $technologies->result();

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
        if(!$this->DATA['SEO']["title"])
            $this->DATA['SEO']["title"]         = config_item("site_title");

        if(!$this->DATA['SEO']["description"])
            $this->DATA['SEO']["description"]       = config_item("site_description");

        $pages = $this->Admin->getTable("pages",false,"title");
        $this->DATA['pages'] = $pages->result();
        $this->DATA['totalSites']       = $this->Admin->getCountTable("sites");
        $this->show($action);

    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not a codeigniter developer, but this error means that `getTable(..)` returned most probably false. So the function was not able to retrieve your table "sites" based on the given parameters.

Comment: Do you load `Admin` model class?

Comment: yes, I do @Naga

Comment: `$recent->result();` - is this right function ?

Comment: show us your model

Comment: I think you mixed with calling model function and active records query in single statement. I don't think it is possible.

Comment: I've added the complete code @NewbeeDev

Comment: @M.Safari include the `Admin` Model where you putted the function `getTable`

Comment: @NewbeeDev Which model? could you please write the code you mean?